# Select last N days till max(date) in Postrges?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I'm struggling to select rows that have their 'date' attribute in the range of last 30 days till the most recent day (max date)

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE (date > MAX(date) FROM table1 - 30)
```

Do I need to to nested select statement to solve it? Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE date > ((select MAX(date) FROM table1)- interval '30 day' )
```

Comment: And if I want to group by id, can I add `GROUP BY id`?

Comment: I do `SELECT id, sum(amount) FROM table1 GROUP BY id WHERE date > ((select MAX(date) FROM table1)- interval '30 day' )` and it gives me `syntax error at or near "WHERE"
`

Comment: SELECT id, sum(amount) FROM table1  WHERE date > ((select MAX(date) FROM table1)- interval '30 day' ) GROUP BY id
group by clause will be after where cluase